# How to make mySQL database at my local accessible from different machines?

Tags: mysql, windows, database-connection

I have mySQL installed at my Windows system which I connect using mySQL Query Browser. I am giving training and I want people to be able to connect to my machines SQL Database

How do I do that? Currently its not allowing the connections.

What settings do I need to modify?

Comment: Your question for starters: you've not said if there is any firewall configured on the machine (it should have one) nor what the Operating System / firewall *is*

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: There is no firewall configured on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1: Check  IP connectivity**

By default it only allows connections from 127.0.0.1.
Are you using windows or linux?

Open **my.cnf** and change bind address to your network IP.

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

More info can easily be found in google. Check [this](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm).

**STEP 2: Check your firewall**

Also, as commented by **@Leandro**, check your windows firewall settings to allow connections to happen.

One easy way to test it is to make a telnet from the client machine to your MySQL network ip, port 3306 and see if connects or get blocked.

**STEP 3: Check mysql user permissions**

Once you have IP connectivity, the user that your alumni are using should have log in permissions from any host. For example if they use root you have to run a query like this:

```
update user set host=’%’ where user=’root’ and host=’ubuntuserv’;
```

You can see more info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql-give-root-user-logon-permission-from-any-host/).

Comment: Be sure to check your firewall also. It could block the necessary port.

Comment: Changing the bind address to the network IP will *block* connections on the loopback address. Setting it 0.0.0.0 means it will accept connections from any address (which is a really bad idea unless you've got a firewall to restrict the hosts/networks which can connect).

Comment: I dont have bind-address parameter. And i am using windows machine. What is host - 'ubunutuserv'

Comment: You should have a bind-address parameter on you my.cnf. Which version of mysql are you using? ubuntuserv is the hostname that is in the table user. Not sure of the content of yours, so do a Select * From User to check it. The idea is replace the content of host by %

Comment: I am having mysql installed with xampp pack in windows. I do not see bind-address in my.cnf

Comment: I didn't use xampp for a long time... Maybe file is named my.ini? or maybe there is an include to another config file (as they did several years ago in Apache)
Are the other settings present in my.cnf (port, user...) ?

Comment: Or is possible that if setting is not there, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. You can try adding it.

Comment: Cool. Just curiosity... Where was your bind-address parameter hidden?

Answer (score -1):

Ask them to use phpMyAdmin to access your database over you IP address. Also put your Apache server online.

Comment: OP wanted to connect to database, not to see the fancy phpmyadmin.